# CSS aligning background-image above background-color set in *:before and *:after

Tags: html, css

I'm making a little Go board, in just CSS, and have got a problem when I put a counter on a point.

HTML:

```
<div class="GoBoard">
  <div class="aa black"></div>
  <div class="ab"></div>
  <div class="ba"></div>
  <div class="bb white"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.GoBoard{
    position:relative;
    background-color: #630;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.GoBoard>div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.GoBoard>div:before, .GoBoard>div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

.GoBoard>div:before {
    left: 50%;
    width: 2%;
    margin-left: -1%;
    height: 100%;
}

.GoBoard>div:after {
    top: 50%;
    height: 2%;
    margin-top: -1%;
    width: 100%;
}

.white{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:none!important;
    z-index: 1!important;
    background-image:    -moz-radial-gradient(15px 15px 45deg, circle cover, #ddd 0%, #555 100%)!important;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(15px 15px,       circle cover, #ddd,    #555)!important;
    background-image:         radial-gradient(15px 15px 45deg, circle cover, #ddd 0%, #555 100%)!important;
}

.black{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image:    -moz-radial-gradient(15px 15px 45deg, circle cover, #333 0%, #000 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(15px 15px,       circle cover, #333,    #000);
    background-image:         radial-gradient(15px 15px 45deg, circle cover, #333 0%, #000 100%);
}
.aa{bottom:0px;left:0px}
.ab{bottom:50px;left:0px}
.ba{bottom:0px;left:50px}
.bb{bottom:50px;left:50px}
```

I used the .GoBoard>div as the #cross from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359787/2044866). And the !important's were to show that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8491958/2044866) doesn't work. Adding [position: relative;](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20069515/2044866) to the .white, with !important takes it out of the board, and without makes no difference. I also tried moving the .white, up the CSS and changing it to .white:before, the former made no difference, and the latter changed the cross line to the color of the circle.

I can think of changing the HTML and CSS to have another class for the cross, but I would prefer if the cross would go below the image. Or having a new div for the cross, which seems like a bit of a waist of a div if you can get this close without it.

tl;dr: How do I get the counter (background-image) above the board cross (background-color)?

Comment: A quick fiddle for your question: http://jsfiddle.net/XCmQ7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MN32Z/)**.

Basically, you will only need 2 `z-index`'s defined in your CSS:

```
.GoBoard{
    z-index: 0;
}

.GoBoard>div:before, .GoBoard>div:after {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The one you have defined under `.white` selector is unnecessary. Also, this is a pretty awesome pure CSS setup!